# App crashes when trying to capture video using a camera intent

Tags: android

I'm following tutorial on Android [website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) on how to capture video using a camera intent, but app crashes when I start it.

I'm not sure if MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO have good value. Everything else is the same as on Android website.

This is what I have:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private static final int CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private Uri fileUri;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //create new Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);  // create a file to save the video
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set the video image quality to high

        // start the Video Capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: What is the error and `public class Mainextends Activity ` should be `public class Main extends Activity ` please post your logcat error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put my money on permissions...

Before starting development on your application with the Camera API,
you should make sure your manifest has the appropriate declarations to
allow use of camera hardware and other related features.

Camera Permission - Your application must request permission to use a
 device camera.

```
<uses-permission> android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Note: If you are using the
camera via an intent, your application does not need to request this
permission. Camera Features - Your application must also declare use
of camera features, for example:

```
<uses-feature> android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Storage Permission - If your application saves images or videos to the device's external storage (SD Card), you must also specify this in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You were right. I didn't had `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

getOutputMediaFile returns null
You should check if external storage is available and write operations on it is allowed.

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }
```

this snippet of code from Android official documentation shows how to check it